# $U(2)$ or $SU(2)$? Interferometers and Jones matrices

Tags: optics, group-theory, quantum-optics, interferometry, matrix-elements

Recently I've been trying to understand why the scattering matrices that describe an interferometer should be $SU(2)$ matrices rather than $U(2)$.
The condition of unitarity is undiscussed as it follows from energy conservation. But why should the determinant be especially 1?

I understand that
$$\textrm{U(2)}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
-B^{*}e^{i\theta} & A^{*}e^{i\theta}
\end{array}\right)\left|A,B\in\mathbb{C},\theta\in\mathbb{R},\left|A\right|^{2}+\left|B\right|^{2}=1\right.\right\} ,$$
while
$$\textrm{SU(2)}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
-B^{*} & A^{*}
\end{array}\right)\left|A,B\in\mathbb{C},\left|A\right|^{2}+\left|B\right|^{2}=1\right.\right\} .$$
If we have input annihilation operators $\hat{a}_{1/2}$ and output $\hat{b}_{1/2}$, than a matrix in $U(2)$ gives
$$\left(\begin{array}{c}
\hat{b}_{1}\\
\hat{b}_{2}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A & B\\
-B^{*}e^{i\theta} & A^{*}e^{i\theta}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
\hat{a}_{1}\\
\hat{a}_{2}
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
A \hat{a}_{1}+ B\hat{a}_{2}\\
e^{i\theta}\left(-B^{*}\hat{a}_{1} + A^{*}\hat{a}_{2}\right)
\end{array}\right).$$

It's not clear to me, how physically this **phase indeterminacy $e^{i\theta}$** in one of the two outputs should be discarded. Nevertheless, if I compute quantities like the number of photons $\hat{b}_{2}^\dagger\hat{b}_{2}$, this phase disappears!

The same situation happens with the Jones formalism, which has always $SU(2)$ matrices.

Comment: Phase indeterminacy is important; look up The Aharanov-Bohm experiment and also the gauge principle in QED, QCD, QFT and even in gravity...

Comment: Which kind of makes me think that when you've made the phase indeterminacy disappear it was merely as a formal exercise and not really due to physical thinking/reasoning.

Comment: It is important, but then why everybody talks about SU(2) interferometry rather than U(2) interferometry? See [SU(2) and SU(1,1) interferometers](https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.33.4033)

Comment: Seems like a waste of time chasing up those links ... why? See my comment above.

Answer (score 2):

Phase is a funny thing. It only has meaning as a relative concept. For this reason, if I have a state $|\psi\rangle$ and I multiply it by some phase factor $|\psi\rangle\exp(i\theta)$ I still have exactly the same state. This phase is not observable. If on the other hand, I have a superposition 
$$|\psi\rangle+|\phi\rangle$$
then another superposition given by 
$$|\psi\rangle\exp(i\theta)+|\phi\rangle$$
would not be the same state again, because it contains a relative phase. This is observable.

So the reason why the phase factor you got is discarded, is because it does not produce a relative phase. That is why you cannot observe it with you number operator.

Comment: I agree: the number operator won't make me observe any relative phase. And since in general, we're not superposing the two output ports of the interferometer, even if there's a relative phase it won't matter. But definitely, some relative phase is produced. Thank you for your contribution! @flippiefanus